# get a data with HTMLagilitypack 5

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to catch some data from a website using HtmlAgilityPack. The data is stored in an object with the property class="translateTxt". I use this code but it returns null

c# code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(Url);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='translateTxt']");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes1)
        {
            string Txt = node.InnerText;
        }
```

html code:

```
<div id="trans" class="tap_mt">
    <div class="tr_brst clearfix">
        <div class="tr_instyle">
            <div class="tr_ext clearfix">
                <div class="translateTxt">
                    hi
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following to get the all descendants div tag's

```
 var findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => 
d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("translateTxt"));
```

Then loop over your `findClasses` variable

Comment: Worked
How Can I Get Value in "var findclasses" ?

Comment: loop through it using foreach and get your values using `InnerText`